# three.js globe is not showing

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, three.js

I am just started to learn three.js and tried to run example on codepen. Example is not able to run or show the globe

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxYXgb

Not sure where i did wrong

var container, stats;
            var camera, scene, renderer;
            var group;
            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

```
        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
            camera.position.z = 500;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            group = new THREE.Group();
            scene.add( group );

            // earth

            var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            loader.load( 'textures/land_ocean_ice_cloud_2048.jpg', function ( texture ) {

                var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 200, 20, 20 );

                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, overdraw: 0.5 } );
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                group.add( mesh );

            } );

            // shadow

            var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
            canvas.width = 128;
            canvas.height = 128;

            var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
            var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(
                canvas.width / 2,
                canvas.height / 2,
                0,
                canvas.width / 2,
                canvas.height / 2,
                canvas.width / 2
            );
            gradient.addColorStop( 0.1, 'rgba(210,210,210,1)' );
            gradient.addColorStop( 1, 'rgba(255,255,255,1)' );

            context.fillStyle = gradient;
            context.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

            var texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture( canvas );

            var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 300, 300, 3, 3 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, overdraw: 0.5 } );

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            mesh.position.y = - 250;
            mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
            group.add( mesh );

            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
            container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
            mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY );

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            render();
            stats.update();

        }

        function render() {

            camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.05;
            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            group.rotation.y -= 0.005;

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
```

Comment: The globe is rendering just fine for me in latest chrome and firefox. are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Your globe is also rendering fine for me...

Comment: @micnil,@wilt,  I fixed it as Image of globe was not pointed to right path.